# Create dummy data for report in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, dummy-data

I have a reporting module for my application, where users can select the template,
When a user selects a template, it will appear in jasper viewer with dummy data. But when the user starts generating the report it will use the data from the database.

I had the idea to first use the .properties file, but there are obstacles, how do I know if the report has not been generated by the original data? While in .jrxml file already exists query to the database, which if no data is entered it will display the null data.

How is the best solution? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

According to me do one thing write static query like :-

```
select 1,2,3,4....n
```

So it will work like static data to your report and it will be easy to change the query and make it dynamic.

In the place of query write above query. so it will work as a dummy data for you.

Comment: Can you explain more detail,please? I can't catch your solution. :/

Comment: please check i modified my answer

Comment: Okay it fix now i use dummy data in Database, :)